# Using Height in Vh less some pixels

Tags: html, height

I have an image set to be 100vh height (fullscreen).
The problem is that I have a Navbar top that made me set a 80px offset for body div, so I need to set an height of my full screen image like (100vh - 80px) does exists some way to do this?

Comment: Please don't post only text, but provide some code

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS *calc* function.

```
height: calc(100vh - 80px);
```

Check [this guide](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_calc.asp) for more information.